# JMS within Tomcat: creation a queue per client?

Tags: java, tomcat, push-notification, jms

I am trying to develop my own server as an web application with Tomcat. I would like to develop a system of push notifications (server->client(s)) and I saw that the principle of JMS is quite interesting for that. I already found some tutorial on Internet about how to use JMS/ActiveMQ on Tomcat (for instance: http://www.idanfridman.com/using-jms-in-tomcat/) . However, it seems that the creation of queues or topics has to be done manually from a xml file (conf/server.xml). Some things do not seem clear to me. Indeed, i would like to know how the creation is exactly handled, if it is possible to create with a java code a queue/topic for each new client(s) (we don't send the same notitifications to every clients). If it is the case, in that case it means that if I have 1000 clients then I have to create 1000 queue in order to handle the notifications of each client.

Thanks in adavance,

S

Comment: why do you need 1000 queues for 1000 clients? if you are planning to push notification? then as i understand,there would be 1 Queue all the clients would connect to it.

Comment: I am talking about 1000 queues because what I am looking for is to notify a client about a specific event (e.g alarm) concerning only this specific client. According to me, if I create only one queue then all clients can receive this alarm. That's why 1000 queues if we have 1000 clients. Futhermore, I would add a topic if server wants to notify all clients with the same event.

Comment: Ok!! So as i understand you want to have different notifications? like Alarm,Meeting etc etc for different clients?What if you can keep all these notification on the same queue and put a selector on queue,you can refer MESSAGE SELECTORS so the required client would get specific notification.

Answer (score 1):

It's certainly possible to create them programmatically, but I doubt you want to use `JMS` (or 1000 JMS queues) for your program.

1000 clients also sounds like a lot for your situation. It seems to me you're looking for something like `WebSockets` instead of `JMS`.